# gitlab-runner has not yet connected error

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab

In my setup gitlab on **Ubuntu 16.04** and after upgrading from gitlab-multi-runner to **gitlab-runner** it is not starting by default.

According to gitlab runner documentation, it should start, just after install and register.

Although I can see registered runner in my admin gitlab runners page, the error

> **runner has not connected yet**

stays forever...

My versions at this moment:

- System: Ubuntu 16.04
- Gitlab: 10.1.1
- Gitlab-runner: 10.1.0

Answer (score 5):

In case you are running into this issue, check these:

1. Check if you have directory named:

> **/home/gitlab-runner/**

If not create it. You can do it by executing: `sudo mkdir /home/gitlab-runner`

2. **Check owners** on this dir. It should be gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner. So if not execute command `sudo chown -R gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner /home/gitlab-runner`

That should solve the problem and you should see gitlab-runner immediately starting in your gitlab admin runners page (you might need to refresh page)...

If not you should try `sudo service gitlab-runner status` and/or check syslog for eventual other errors.

Comment: That solved for me but not in /home/gitlab-runner but under /var/lib/gitlab-runner

Answer (score 1):

For me (on Windows though) the solution was to run gitlab-runner.exe as administrator. Kudos to [this blog post](https://codereviewvideos.com/blog/how-i-solved-new-runner-has-not-connected-yet-in-gitlab-ci/) for pushing in the right direction.